# Outlook Macro that will copy an email I flag and put it in a folder

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

How can I move copy of emails I flag and put them in a folder?

For example, John Doe sends me an email, I flag it, the original email stays in my inbox but a copy of the email goes into a folder called **`"Follow Up"`**.  Can someone help me?

**EDIT:**

The code below is extremely close to what I want but it's moving the original email to the folder instead of a copy.  It's also not targeting the flagged email.

```
Sub FollowUp()
On Error Resume Next

Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim moveToFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem



Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'Define path to the target folder
Set moveToFolder = ns.Folders("MainFolder").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Follow Up")

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
MsgBox ("No item selected")
Exit Sub
End If

If moveToFolder Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Target folder not found!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Move Macro Error"
End If

For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
If moveToFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
  If objItem.Class = olMail Then
     objItem.Move moveToFolder
  End If
End If
Next

Set objItem = Nothing
Set moveToFolder = Nothing
Set ns = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Your asking to move copy only if the mail item is flagged? Automatically or by selecting?

Comment: By selecting.  If there is an email that is in my inbox and I click the flag to the right, I want it to make a copy of the flagged email and put it in a folder.  I want it to be automatic every time I flag an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what your trying to do, add the following code to ***`ThisOutlookSession`*** and then restart your outlook.

Code will automatically move copy of flagged Mailitem

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder  As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
    Set Items = olFolder.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olInbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim ItemCopy As MailItem

    Set olNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olInbox = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set olFolder = olInbox.Folders("Follow Up")

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Debug.Print Item

        If Item.FlagStatus = olFlagMarked Then
            Set ItemCopy = Item.Copy ' Copy Flagged item
             ItemCopy.Move olFolder ' Move Copied item
        End If

        Set Item = Nothing
        Set ItemCopy = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Press **`Alt+F11`**

[image]

double click **`ThisOutlookSession`** and paste the code in there, then restart your outlook and flag your mail item.

Comment: I'm not sure if I implemented this correctly.  I created a macro and inserted the code and tested it and nothing happened.  I saved the macro, closed Outlook, reopened it and ran the macro again and still nothing.  Could you tell me where 'ThisOutLookSession' is located?